# Find an object inside from another object with property

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this data and I want retrieve an object which has this property `selectedAddOn: 'aa'`. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```js
data = {
  selectedParentName: 'Choice',
  addOnTypeDropDownArray: [{
    value: 'aa',
    viewValue: 'aa (Choice)',
    price: 12,
    key: 0.42298649258214116,
    type: 'Choice'
  }, {
    value: 'dd',
    viewValue: 'dd (Choice)',
    price: 323,
    key: 0.10174316295283248,
    type: 'Choice'
  }],
  multiSelect: false,
  label: 'Size',
  addOnTypeData: [{
    type: 'Size',
    name: '',
    key: 0.9570293430160035,
    parentId: 0.42298649258214116,
    selectedAddOn: 'aa',
    value: null,
    allowMultiSelect: false
  }, {
    type: 'Size',
    name: '',
    key: 0.8886483410557189,
    parentId: 0.10174316295283248,
    selectedAddOn: 'dd',
    value: null,
    allowMultiSelect: false
  }]
};
```

Comment: Use ` `` ` backticks to format your code

Comment: As mentioned in above comment, use the correct format tools when using large blocks of code. Also, check it out the guide on how to make a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You question is missing the basics, what have you already tried? What were your results? What did you research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [`array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to loop through `array values` in `data` and search for a match.

```js
let aaArray = [];
Object.values(data).forEach((value) => {
    if (value instanceof Array) {
        let aa = value.filter((object) => object.selectedAddOn === 'aa');
        if (aa.length) aaArray.push(...aa);
    }
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
let data = {
    selectedParentName: 'Choice',
    addOnTypeDropDownArray: [
        {
            value: 'aa',
            viewValue: 'aa (Choice)',
            price: 12,
            key: 0.42298649258214116,
            type: 'Choice',
        },
        {
            value: 'dd',
            viewValue: 'dd (Choice)',
            price: 323,
            key: 0.10174316295283248,
            type: 'Choice',
        },
    ],
    multiSelect: false,
    label: 'Size',
    addOnTypeData: [
        {
            type: 'Size',
            name: '',
            key: 0.9570293430160035,
            parentId: 0.42298649258214116,
            selectedAddOn: 'aa',
            value: null,
            allowMultiSelect: false,
        },
        {
            type: 'Size',
            name: '',
            key: 0.8886483410557189,
            parentId: 0.10174316295283248,
            selectedAddOn: 'dd',
            value: null,
            allowMultiSelect: false,
        },
    ],
};

let aaArray = [];
Object.values(data).forEach((value) => {
    if (value instanceof Array) {
        let aa = value.filter((object) => object.selectedAddOn === 'aa');
        if (aa.length) aaArray.push(...aa);
    }
});

console.log(aaArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

use

`data.addOnTypeData[0].selectedAddOn`

for first item.

you can use loop also

```
public propertyFilter = (property) = >{
 for (let index= 0; index < data.addOnTypeData.length;index++){
  if(data.addOnTypeData[index]['selectedAddOn'] === property){
    return data.addOnTypeData[index];
   }
 }
 return 'No matches found';
}
propertyFilter('aa')
console.log(propertyFilter('aa'))
```

Comment: I have to return an object which has property `selectedAddOn='aa'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) like this

`const addOnTypeFound = data.addOnTypeData.filter(addOn => addOn.selectedAddon === 'aa')`